# How to connect to Azure keyvault from SpringBoot application for local development using MSI

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am trying to connect to Azure KeyVault from my locally running Spring Boot Application. I can't keep those secrets to be saved in keyvault in different properties or yaml during dev, because my application will generate and delete so many secrets and tokens to be saved in keyvault in the run time.

I am aware of the process in which we can create an Azure service principal from your application registration. And use

azure.keyvault.client-id
azure.keyvault.client-key

in application.properties to connect.

But it may not be allowed to be created Azure service principal in our case. So is there any way to connect to key vault using MSI from locally running SpringBoot application.

using MSI_ENDPOINT
 and MSI_SECRET

Comment: If anybody has tried to connect using REST , sharing a code snippet will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there any way to connect to key vault using MSI from locally running SpringBoot application.
>   using MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET

I don't think you can use `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET` get the token in local, it just works when the web app published in the cloud.

> But it may not be allowed to be created Azure service principal in our case.

As you know, you can use the service principal `client id` and `secret(key)` to access the keyvault. Actually, when enabling the MSI of the web app, it will create a service principal in your Azure AD tenant automatically. So you can just use the client id and secret of it.

Navigate to the portal -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `Enterprise applications` -> search for your web app name(select the `Application Type` with `All Applications`), then you get the `client id(application id)`.

**Note**: Remember to check the object id of the service principal with that in your web app -> `Identity`, make sure you use the correct one.

[image]

For the service principal secret, you could create it via powershell like below(your account need the admin role `Application administrator` or `Global administrator` in your AAD tenant).

```
New-AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential -ObjectId <service principal object id>
```

[image]

Then you will be able to access the keyvault with the client id and secret. For details in java, you can refer to this [link](http://stratogator.com/2017/10/20/how-to-access-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-java/).

Comment: Are youif I create an Azure webApp..... and add it to access policy of the keyvault and generate a secret for the webapp.....now will be able to connect to keyvault from locally running springboot application using them as client key and client id.....isn't it...???

Comment: @ArnavKarformaa Yes, you can. Note the secret I mean is the secret of the service principal, not the secret in the keyvault.

Comment: It may sound silly...but I don't have so much knowledge about cloud services...... so will it be also possible with an Azure App Service

Comment: @ArnavKarforma Yes, it is possible with a web app(app service), just follow my steps. If you are not familiar with Azure, I recommend you to learn something about Azure AD first.

Comment: @ArnavKarforma Could you accept my reply if it is helpful?

Comment: Yes sure... let me try it and will aceept it in a while

Comment: For running it from powerShell I might need admin access each time (and even to install different Modules there)...is there any way to create AzureADServicePrincipalPasswordCredential from the Azure portal.... It will be a great help

Comment: @ArnavKarforma You could run the powershell command directly in [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview), no need to install any module. Also, make sure your account which login the portal has the admin role(`Application administrator` or `Global administrator`) in your tenant. There is no UI to create the password for the service principal which was created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it using those variables because locally there is no Azure AD Identity Registered on your local machine and as such Microsoft didn't build any MSI emulator so no variables will be set.

I can recommend what Microsoft did in their .NET library

1. Run Azure CLI and log in
2. In code check for variables and if they don't exist then run CLI command

   ```
   az account get-access-token --resource 'https://vault.azure.net'
   ```

In CLI simply log into either principal or your account. Make sure to add this account/your account to KeyVault policy.

I know it's weird but I you can even check it [HERE on their GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/834bebd91c55d20eede0800d58a9a5bba654fb5e/sdk/mgmtcommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/TokenProviders/AzureCliAccessTokenProvider.cs).

I might have an article that will help you in case you want more details

https://marczak.io/posts/2019/07/securing-websites-with-msi/

Comment: But I would need to do read and write into my keyvault very often....from my web application running locally....will I get any help in that with this way?

Comment: Yes this should work for that scenario too. But if you work with token often then use caching so you don't generate token this much, it's valid for 30 mins.

Comment: Please consider marking this as an answer if this helped you.